# 3d Touch Not Available on iPhone 6s+

Tags: ios, swift, force-touch

I am trying to add 3d touch into my application. I am trying to enable the user to use force touch on a UITableViewCell, like shown in [this project](https://github.com/Sweefties/iOS9-NewAPI-3DTouch-PeekAndPop-Example). I am running this code:

```
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.Available {
    registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: view)
} else {
    print("unavailable")
}
```

I have tried running it on an iPhone 6s+, but I receive "unavailable" in my logs. Why can I not use 3d touch on a 3d touch-supported device? Thanks for your help.

Comment: when did you execute the code? at `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else/

Comment: Yes, I ran this in viewDidLoad

Comment: would you mind checking if 3D Touch is enabled on your device? go to Settings > General > Accessibility > 3D Touch

Comment: Yes. It is enabled on my device

Comment: I've encountered this problem before. The solution I'm using now is overriding `traitCollectionDidChange:` in the view controller and access the `forceTouchCapability` there.

Comment: Yes! That works! If you could post an official answer, I will accept it. Thanks @Cheng-YuHsu!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just found some reference about 3D Touch APIs: according to the [3D Touch APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html) documentation, Apple suggested that developers to read `forceTouchCapability` in `traitCollectionDidChange:` delegate method.

For example, you may check the value in your view controller using:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    switch traitCollection.forceTouchCapability {
    case .Available:
        print("Available")
    case .Unavailable:
        print("Unavailable")
    case .Unknown:
        print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.